# Using TimeSeriesSplit in RandomSearchCV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series

I want to use `TimeSeriesSplit` in `RandomSearchCV`.

Look at the example below.

```py
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = ['one', 'two'])
df.index = [0,0,0,1,1,2]

df
    one two
0   1   2
0   3   4
0   1   2
1   3   4
1   1   2
2   3   4
```

Say I want to split `X` such that:

1. In the first split, train set corresponds to rows with index `0,0,0` and validation set are rows with indices `1,1`
2. In the second split, train set are rows with index `0,0,0,1,1` and validation set rows with index `2`

I tried using `TimeSeriesSplit` with `n_splits = 2` but could not get the result I wanted.

```py
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2)
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(df.index):
    print(df.index[train_index], df.index[test_index])

Int64Index([0, 0], dtype='int64') Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype='int64') Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

P.S: If not TimeSeriesSplit can I use PredefinedSplit?

Comment: I am not sure what you did when editing the question but you should at least credit my edits to your question as they have improved it (and you are using them)

Comment: also, could you please reformulate the question. It is not clear if you want help creating the various data sets or you want help running `RandomSearchCV`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the rows based on index, you can use `loc` method from `DataFrames`:

For example for your initial data split you have:

```py
>>> df.loc[[0]] # train set
   one  two
0    1    2
0    3    4
0    1    2
>>> df.loc[[1]] # validation set
   one  two
1    3    4
1    1    2
```

For the second split you have:

```py
>>> df.loc[[0,1]] # train set
   one  two
0    1    2
0    3    4
0    1    2
1    3    4
1    1    2
>>> df.loc[[2]] # validation set
   one  two
2    3    4
```

Comment: Sure, this is fine. How do I use these 2 dataframes in RandomSearchCV?

Comment: I don't know, haven't used `RandomSearchCV`